# Application crashing when calling a c++ code in .NET

Tags: c++, .net

I am calling a c++ method from .NET like below,

```
    [DllImport("CPCModule.dll", EntryPoint = "FuncName", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern long FuncName([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string inFile, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]ref string OutFile);

    Public Void test()
    {
        string altFileName = string.Empty;
        string FileName = "{MyInputFullPath}"
        long ret;
        ret = ClassName.FuncName(FileName, ref altFileName);
        ........
    }
```

The C++ code is as follows,

```
   static ICPC* pCPC;
   extern "C" long _stdcall FuncName(char* inFile, char** outFile)
   {
      ......
      hr = pCPC->UPPat2File(inFile, outFile);
      return hr;
   }
```

In the .NET code, i am passing a input file. This input file will be decoded in the method UPPat2File and  put it in a output file. After the above code, the outFile is filled with proper value and the hr also return S_OK.

But after the end of the method, it was supposed to come back to .NET code (and the altFileName should be filled with the outFile). But instead it is crashing with the below exception, "An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in .NETdllname.dll. Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." It is not coming back to .NET code.

Comment: Looks like a concurrency issue. Have you disposed the file reader/writers after use ?

Comment: Yes. Also the method 'FuncName' is called in many places (c++ code) and it works fine. First time, I am trying to call this in .NET code.

Comment: Generally with interop it's just making sure everything aligns, and fiddling things till it works. You've specified `CharSet.Unicode` but then `UnmanagedType.LPStr` which is ANSI, I bet that's what confusing it. Either remove the charset (which means it will use ANSI), or change the string types to be Unicode . Lastly you may want to try setting `outFile` to be a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Removed the CharSet.Unicode. Still throwing exception for the same reason.

Comment: Tried StringBuilder too. Again the same problem.